# Set new time after the actual one

Tags: java, date, time

I'm trying to create a method that prints e.g. actual time of arrival (now) and then it prints the time of departure which I want to set plus 3 minutes compared to the first one.

```
public void updateTimes(){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");
    this.arrivalTime = new Date();
    this.departureTime = this.arrivalTime.plusMinutes(3);
}
```

Departure time doesn't work as intended.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: *"Departure time doesn't work as intended"* - aha!? In what way does it not work?

Comment: Also, your naming style (`T1m3$`), leaves me wondering.

Comment: `java.util.Date` does not have a `plusMinutes` method. Also, a date cannot conceptually encapsulate information about minutes. A date is simply days, months and years.

Comment: @Michael On you second point; a `java.util.Date` actually contains both date and time information.

Comment: @marstran `java.util.Date` is well known to have been horribly designed. What's your point?

Comment: Using SimpleDateFormat I was able to use Date for printing H:mm, not sure if is totally correct though. Which class could I use to edit info about minutes?

Comment: @HeRoy please see the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package introduced in Java 8.

Comment: @Michael Yes, that's what I pointed out. You said "a date cannot conceptually encapsulate information about minutes". You were talking about `java.util.Date` in your previous sentence, so I assumed that was the date you meant.

Comment: @marstran well `java.util.Date` is not conceptual

Comment: @Michael My only point was that it is easy to misread your comment...

Comment: Not only is `Date` long outmoded, `SimpleDateFormat` is so and even more troublesome. I recommend you throw both classes out and look into [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) for a solution to your task.

Comment: As commented by Ole V.V., the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

[java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) not have `plusMinutes`.

It can be better if you use Java 8, with [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) library :

```
LocalTime arrivalTime = LocalTime.now();//Current time
LocalTime departureTime = arrivalTime.plusMinutes(3);//plus 3 minutes to the time

//Then you can format the time
String result = departureTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using Calendar looks like:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(arrivalTime); // only if different from "now"
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 3);
departureTime = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: [You should prefer `java.time` classes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html). The API is better, they are immutable and thread-safe.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Of course you are right. But there's still so much legacy code around, that I think it's good to know how to do it with JDK7, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like below:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");
    Date date = new Date();

    System.out.println("arrival time = " + sdf.format(date));

    int min = date.getMinutes();
    date.setMinutes(min+3);

    System.out.println("departure time = " + sdf.format(date));
```